# iOS Swift - UITableView didselectrowatindexpath crashes

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, didselectrowatindexpath

First of all, let me say that this is a noobish question so please bear with me here :D. I have a tableview embedded in a navigation control and it is my main view. There is an "Add" button where I can add "things" then when that is triggered it shows the added item on the table view and also switches back to the main view controller with the code below

```
@IBAction func buttonAddPost_Click(sender: UIButton) {
postMgr.addPost(titleBox.text, description: descriptionBox.text, postDate: date)
self.navigationController.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(true)
}
```

Again the above code takes me back to the main table view controller just fine.

But when I click on a cell to take me to a more detailed view, the app crashes. Here is the code

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) {
let listingPage = self.storyboard.instantiateViewControllerIdentifier("listingPage") as PostListingTableViewController
self.navigationController.pushViewController(listingPage, animated: true)
}
```

"listingPage" is the storyboard ID for the new view controller I'm trying to go to. I have used the above technique a few times somewhere else and worked just fine but I'm not sure what's wrong here.

Error I get:
Thread 1
0  swift_dynamicCast and it highlights 0x1d7150: pushl %ebp     Thread 1: EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=EXC_I386_BPT)
1
2 Exchange.PostlistTableViewController ([app name].[class name]) and it highlights the didselectrowatindexpath
.
.
.

Please help...

KM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception tells you what the problem is - You are casting the view controller `as PostListingTableViewController` but the object type that is returned is `PostlistTableViewController` so the cast generates an exception.

You need to determine what the correct class name is and either update your storyboard or your `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` so that they are consistent - either Postlist or PostListing.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It was supposed to be ListingPageViewController not PostListingTableController. +1 for you sir